# Java socket application sends additional bytes while trying to send file

Tags: java, sockets, file-io, stream, java-io

My program is a typicall server-client application. The problem is, when I try to send a file, for some reason client socket recives more bytes than server socket sends. To make it more strange, those bytes are at the beginning, and their number changes depending on file size. When I tried sending 1x1px file, there was 6bytes offset (6 bytes of added data, which, if I skipped them, gave proper image) , whereas 800x600 byte has larger one (totally second output file is bigger than second input by 56 bytes).  After searching over the internet the only 2 suggestions I found were to try to clear the bufer beforehand, and I think I tried but it simply "ate" my first inStream.read().
The second was connected to the way pacages are sent, that the size has to be multiply of some number? But it seemed strange, for wouldn't they add some space at the end of the file, not at the beginning?

Client class

```
public class Client{

import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class Client implements Runnable {
static Socket clientSocket = null;
static Socket iClientSocket = null;
static PrintWriter out = null;
static BufferedReader in = null;
static InputStream iin = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
    String host = args[0];

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);
        iClientSocket = new Socket(host, port);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        iin = iClientSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + host);
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for " + "the connection to: "
                + host);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    String userInput;

    try {
        new Thread(new Client()).start();
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
        }
        System.out.println("Closing sockets, closing streams");

        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        iClientSocket.close();
        clientSocket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {
    String a = null;

    try {
        while (true) {
            if((a = in.readLine()) == null)
                continue;
            //System.out.println("Tried to read");
            int n;
            try{
                n = Integer.valueOf(a);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println(a);
                n=1;
                //continue;
            }
            a = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                a += in.readLine() + "\n";
            System.out.println(a);
            // if(a.contains("POST"),)
            if (a.compareToIgnoreCase("EXIT") == 0) {
                System.out.println("Exiting");
                break;
            }
            if (a.endsWith("Sending File\n")) {

                System.out.println("Recieving image.");
                a=in.readLine();
                a=in.readLine();
                FileOutputStream iout = new FileOutputStream(a);
                int fileSize=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                int total=0;
                int step = 1500;
                int bufferSize = 0;
                // if(step>fileSize)
                // bufferSize=(int) fileSize;
                // else
                bufferSize = step;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int read=0;

                while (fileSize-total>0 && (read = iin.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, fileSize-total))) > 0) {
                    iout.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    //out.println("saved packet");
                    total+=read;

                }
                iout.flush();
                iout.close();
                System.out.println("Image recieved");

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}
```

}

Server class, responsible for sending

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

static ServerSocket serverSocket;
Socket tempSocket;
Socket tempSocket2;
static volatile List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
static boolean waitForNew = true;
PrintWriter tempOut;
volatile User[] tempUser;
volatile boolean isReadingN = false;

public Server(Socket _s, Socket _s2) {
    tempSocket = _s;
    tempSocket2 = _s2;
}

public Server(PrintWriter nOut, User[] user) {
    tempOut = nOut;
    tempUser = user;
    isReadingN = true;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (isReadingN) {
        while (true) {
            if (tempUser != null && tempUser.length > 0
                    && tempUser[0] != null)
                break;
        }
        User[] myUser = new User[1];
        myUser[0] = tempUser[0];
        // myUser[0]=usersList.
        while (true) {
            if (myUser[0].isCurrentlyLoggedIn() == false)
                break;
            String[] toSend = null;
            if (myUser[0].isNotificable())
                toSend = myUser[0].printNotifications().split("\n");
            else
                continue;
            //tempOut.println("");
            tempOut.println("1");
            tempOut.println(myUser[0].getName());
            int sendL=toSend.length;
            tempOut.println(String.valueOf(sendL));
            for (int i = 0; i < toSend.length; i++)
                tempOut.println(toSend[i]);
        }
        return;
    }
    Socket clientSocket = tempSocket;
    System.out.println("Initiating conversation with the client");
    String inputLine;
    try {
        System.out.print("creating server out...");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),
                true);
        Socket iClientSocket = tempSocket2;
        ObjectOutputStream iout = new ObjectOutputStream(
                iClientSocket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("OK!");
        System.out.print("creating server in...");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("OK!");
        System.out.print("creating server image streams...");
        System.out.println("OK!");
        System.out.println("Server initiating conversation");
        User[] currentUser = new User[1];
        new Thread(new Server(out, currentUser)).start();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            boolean[] downloadPicture = new boolean[1];
            downloadPicture[0] = false;
            String input = Command.call(inputLine, currentUser, usersList,
                    downloadPicture);
            String[] toSend;
            if (input != null) {
                toSend = input.split("\n");
            } else
                toSend = new String[0];
            out.println(String.valueOf(toSend.length));
            for (int i = 0; i < toSend.length; i++)
                out.println(toSend[i]);
            if (downloadPicture[0]) {
                out.println("1");
                out.println("Sending File");

                System.out.println("Sending File");
                String[] temp = inputLine.split(" ");
                String path = temp[temp.length - 1];
                path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
                File f = new File(path);
                temp=path.split("\\\\");
                String fileName=temp[temp.length-1];
                out.println("1");
                out.println(fileName);
                if (f.exists()) {
                    FileInputStream iin = new FileInputStream(path);

                    long fileSize = f.length();

                    out.println(fileSize);

                    int step = 1500;
                    int bufferSize = 0;
                    if (step > fileSize)
                        bufferSize = (int) fileSize;
                    else
                        bufferSize = step;
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    iout.flush();
                    while ((bytesRead = iin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        //iout.flush();
                        iout.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        // System.out.println(in.readLine());
                    }
                    // iout.write(buffer,0,0);
                    iout.flush();
                    System.out.println("File sent.");
                    iin.close();

                } else{
                    out.println("1");
                    out.println("Error: File does not exit.");}
            } else
                //out.println(" ");
            if (inputLine.equals("EXIT")) {
                waitForNew = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // End communication graciously
        System.out.println("Closing sockets, closing streams");
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IIOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Could not find file");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create socket on port given in argument, localhost
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out
                .println("Not enough arguments. Try Server <port number>");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    int port = 0;
    try {
        port = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Application start");

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Created socket on port " + port);
    } catch (NumberFormatException c) {
        System.out
                .println("Incorrect port number. Try Server <port number>");
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    // Waiting for client
    System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    Socket iClientSocket = null;
    while (waitForNew) {
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            iClientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            new Thread(new Server(clientSocket, iClientSocket)).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Accept failed: " + port);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

}
 }
```

Command class, manipulating commands on server side, returning output.

```
 public class Command {
static volatile List<Status> statusList = new ArrayList<Status>();
static Object block_statusList = new Object();

public static String call(String arg, User[] user, List<User> userlist,
        boolean[] downloadPicture) {

    String command[] = arg.split(" ");
    if (command.length == 0)
        return "";
    else if (command[0].compareTo("LOGIN") == 0)
        return login(command, user, userlist);
    else if (command[0].compareTo("EXIT") == 0)
        return exit(command, user, userlist);
    else if (user == null || user.length != 1 || user[0] == null
            || !user[0].isCurrentlyLoggedIn())
        return "You need to login first. Try LOGIN <username>";
    else if (command[0].compareTo("LOGOUT") == 0)
        return logout(command, user, userlist);
    else if (command[0].compareTo("POST") == 0)
        return post(command, user, userlist, downloadPicture);
    else if (command[0].compareTo("TIMELINE") == 0)
        return timeline(command, user, userlist);
    else if (command[0].compareTo("FOLLOW") == 0)
        return follow(command, user, userlist);
    else if (command[0].compareTo("UNFOLLOW") == 0)
        return unfollow(command, user, userlist);
    else if (command[0].compareTo("VIEWSTATUS") == 0)
        return viewstatus(command, user, userlist);
    else if (command[0].compareTo("LISTUSER") == 0)
        return listuser(command, user, userlist);
    else if (command[0].compareTo("VIEWUSER") == 0)
        return viewuser(command, user, userlist);
    else if (command[0].compareTo("COMMENT") == 0)
        return comment(command, user, userlist);

    else
        return "Command not recognized";
}

private static String logout(String[] arg, User[] user, List<User> userlist) {
    if (arg.length != 1)
        return "Wrong number of parameters. LOGOUT does not take any parameters";
    user[0].setCurrentlyLoggedIn(false);
    return "Logged out.";
}

private static String[] parseArg(String[] arg) {
    int startCommas = 0;
    int endCommas = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
        if (startCommas == 0 && arg[i].startsWith("\""))
            startCommas = i;
        if (startCommas != 0 && arg[i].endsWith("\""))
            endCommas = i;
    }
    if (startCommas != endCommas) {
        String[] newArg = new String[arg.length + startCommas - endCommas];
        for (int i = 0; i < startCommas; i++)
            newArg[i] = arg[i];
        newArg[startCommas] = "";
        for (int i = startCommas; i < endCommas; i++)
            newArg[startCommas] += arg[i] + " ";
        newArg[startCommas] += arg[endCommas];
        for (int i = endCommas + 1; i < arg.length; i++)
            newArg[i - endCommas] = arg[i];
        return newArg;
    }
    return arg;
}

private static String comment(String[] arg, User[] user, List<User> userlist) {
    synchronized (block_statusList) {
        arg = parseArg(arg);
        int SID;
        if (arg.length != 3)
            return "Wrong number of parameters. Try COMMENT <Status ID> \"Comment text\"";
        if (arg[2].charAt(0) != '"'
                || arg[2].charAt(arg[1].length() - 1) != '"')
            return "Text of message has to be in quotation marks. Try  POST \"post text\"";
        String temp = arg[2].substring(1, arg[2].length() - 1);
        try {
            SID = Integer.valueOf(arg[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return "Status ID has to be a number. Try COMMENT <Status ID> \"Comment text\"";
        }
        Comment c = new Comment(temp, user);
        statusList.get(SID).addComment(c);
        return "Comment succeeded";
    }
}

private static String viewuser(String[] arg, User[] user,
        List<User> userlist) {
    synchronized (block_statusList) {
        if (arg.length != 2)
            return "Wrong number of parameters. Try VIEWUSER <user>";
        String r = "";
        for (User u : userlist)
            if (u.getName().compareTo(arg[1]) == 0)
                r = u.printUser();
        return r;
    }
}

private static String listuser(String[] arg, User[] user,
        List<User> userlist) {
    if (arg.length != 1)
        return "Wrong number of parameters. LISTUSER doesn't take any parameters";
    String r = "";
    for (User u : userlist)
        r += u.getName() + "\n";
    return r;
}

private static String viewstatus(String[] arg, User[] user,
        List<User> userlist) {
    synchronized (block_statusList) {
        int SID;
        if (arg.length != 2)
            return "Wrong number of parameters. Try VIEWSTATUS <Status ID>";
        try {
            SID = Integer.valueOf(arg[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return "Status ID has to be a number. Try  VIEWSTATUS <Status ID>";
        }
        if (SID >= statusList.size())
            return "Status ID too big.";
        return statusList.get(SID).printWithComments();
    }
}

private static String unfollow(String[] arg, User[] user,
        List<User> userlist) {
    if (arg.length != 2)
        return "Wrong number of parameters. Try UNFOLLOW <username>";
    boolean removed = false;
    for (User u : userlist) {
        if (u.getName().compareTo(arg[1]) == 0) {
            user[0].removeFriend(arg[1]);
            u.removeFollower(user[0].getName());
            removed = true;
        }
    }
    if (!removed)
        return "User not found.";
    return "Follow succeded. " + user[0].printFriends();
}

private static String follow(String[] arg, User[] user, List<User> userlist) {
    if (arg.length != 2)
        return "Wrong number of parameters. Try FOLLOW <username>";
    if(user[0]!=null && user.length!=0 && user[0]!=null && user[0].getName().compareTo(arg[1])==0)
        return "You cannot follow yourself. Try FOLLOW <username>";
    User[] followed = null;
    for (User u : userlist) {
        if (u.getName().compareTo(arg[1]) == 0) {
            followed = new User[1];
            followed[0] = u;
            user[0].addFriend(followed);
            followed[0].addFollower(user);
        }
    }
    if (followed == null)
        return "User not found.";
    return "Follow succeded. Current " + user[0].printFriends();
}

public static String login(String[] arg, User[] user, List<User> userslist) {
    if (arg.length != 2)
        return "Wrong number of parameters. Try LOGIN <username>";
    if (user.length > 0 && user[0] != null) {
        if (user[0].isCurrentlyLoggedIn())
            return "User already logged in. Try logging out first";
    }
    for (User l : userslist) {
        if (l.getName().compareTo(arg[1]) == 0) {
            if (l.isCurrentlyLoggedIn())
                return "That user is already logged in.";
            user[0] = l;
            user[0].setCurrentlyLoggedIn(true);
            return "Login succeeded";
        }
    }

    User newUser = new User(arg[1]);
    userslist.add(newUser);
    user[0] = newUser;
    user[0].setCurrentlyLoggedIn(true);
    return "Login succeeded. Created new user.";
}

public static String post(String[] arg, User[] user, List<User> userslist,
        boolean[] downloadPicture) {
    arg = parseArg(arg);
    if (arg.length != 2 && arg.length != 3)
        return "Wrong number of parameters. Try POST \"post text\"";
    if (arg[1].charAt(0) != '"'
            || arg[1].charAt(arg[1].length() - 1) != '"')
        return "Text of message has to be in quotation marks. Try  POST \"post text\"";
    String temp = arg[1].substring(1, arg[1].length() - 1);
    Status s;
    try {
        s = new Status(temp, statusList.size(), user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Could not create Status");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error";
    }
    if(arg.length==3)
    s.hasImage(arg[2]);
    user[0].addStatus(s);
    statusList.add(s);
    if (arg.length == 3)
        downloadPicture[0] = true;

    return "Successfully added status";

}

public static String timeline(String[] arg, User[] user,
        List<User> userslist) {
    if (arg.length != 1)
        return "Wrong number of parameters. TIMELINE doesn't take any parameters";
    List<Status> Timeline = new ArrayList<Status>();
    Timeline.addAll(user[0].getStats());
    for (User l : user[0].getFriends())
        Timeline.addAll(l.getStats());
    Collections.sort(Timeline);
    String result = "";
    for (Status s : Timeline)
        result += s.print() + "\n" + "Comments[" + s.getComments().size()
                + "]\n\n";
    return result;
}

public static String exit(String[] arg, User[] user, List<User> userslist) {
    if (arg.length != 1)
        return "Wrong number of parameters. EXIT doesn't take any parameters";
    if (user[0] != null)
        user[0].setCurrentlyLoggedIn(false);
    return "EXIT";
}

 }
```

Adding notifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't sending extra bytes, and you aren't receiving extra bytes, but you are certainly writing extra bytes to the file at the receiving end.

Your sending code is correct, your receiving code is not. Have a look at the difference between the `write()` calls. One uses the receive count: one does not. Former is correct. The way to copy a stream in Java is as follows:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

at both ends. However in this case as you keeping the socket open for further commands, you need to send the image size ahead of the image, and you need a way of sending and receiving commands that won't interfere with the images, which `BufferedReader` cannot accomplish. So you need to use `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream`, like so:

```
// At the sender
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.writeUTF(command);
// ...
out.writeLong(imageSize);
// then the copy loop, reading from the image file.

// At the receiver
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
String command = in.readUTF();
// ...
// image reading code
long imageSize = in.readLong();
long total = 0;
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while (total < imageSize && (count = in.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.MIN(buffer.length, imageSize-total))) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
  total += count;
}
out.close();
```

Modulo bugs.

Comment: It appears my image is still garbage (at least the number of bits is now correct). I changed my receivig code to what you can see in edit.

Comment: What on earth is `bytesRead = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())` supposed to do? All I can see is that it (1) tries to read data that isn't being sent and (2) uses a `BufferedReader` that is going to steal data from the image. Get rid of it. Your sending copy loop should be identical to your receiving copy loop, which is correct.

Comment: in (and out) is separate InputStream, which also allows communication between client and server, but this time using simple Strings

Comment: @Xyzk So you haven't posted all your code. How about you do that? and how about you explain how the sender can know what to send *every time around the receive loop?* and how about you implement my suggestion to 'get rid of it'?

Comment: I am trying to do so, simply you have written that I should use write call that uses receive count, in order to use that I need to have the length of the send file. I changed the original code to my current version.

Comment: @Xyzk The receive count is returned by the read() method, as in the code that I said works. I didn't say anything about sending additional data. Do read more carefully please.

Comment: Tried removing anythin unnecessary, still getting garbage at the beginning.

Comment: @Xyzk I don't know what 'remove anything unnecessary' means, but if it still doesn't work you are still doing it wrong. `read()` returns a count, like so: `int count = read(...);`. You need to use that count in the write method, like so: `out.write(buffer, 0, count);` Just like your first code sample which I have already told you is correct.

Comment: And I am using that count in `iout.write(buffer,0,bytesRead)`

Comment: @Xyzk What is all that junk that allocates a new buffer supposed to be for? and reading both lines and byte arrays from the socket? That can never work. You are massively overcomplicating this. Just read bytes and write them until you've read enough.

Comment: I'm reading bytes from different socket than lines, which I use in different class. Removed new buffer allocation. But the thing remains, that the first few bytes in buffer are garbage, and all "proper" content is moved a few bytes. Does iout.write attach some header to each sent packet?

Comment: @XyxK No. Any data you receive is data you sent. Get rid of the available() test. You don't want to stop reading before you have all the data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26984/discussion-between-xyzk-and-ejp)

Comment: Your other problem is that you are using both `BufferedReader` and the socket input directly. `BufferedReader` will buffer, and steal data from the incoming image. Redo the whole thing with the code I am editing in above.

Comment: Formatted to what can be seen in edit. filesize is proper value, the problem appears to be the fact, that file does NOT recieve required number of bytes. As in, the sum of sizes of all recived packages, is smaller than file size (the value of file size is correct)

Comment: Try my code, please. You still have a pointless call to `available()` for example, several hours after I said to remove it.

Comment: Sorry, I have actually made error while editing the stackoverflow code. Have been working on that for over 24h. I removed it.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? And I mean *all* of it: without the pointless guessing at a buffersize when you can use 8192 everywhere, without the `BufferedReader`, *with* the `DataInput/OutputStreams`, and all the rest of it.

Comment: Client was reading data, the first 9000 bytes were ok. Total, it should have recieved 11176 bytes. After that, however, it has recieved only 1294 bytes. Then, it went once again to while loop condition `while (fileSize-total>0 && (read = iin.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, fileSize-total))) > 0)` where it halted waiting for more bytes.No exception has been thrown.

Comment: Then you either sent the wrong length, or you haven't sent all the data, or you haven't removed the `BufferedReader` yet, or you are using a `BufferedOutputStream` at the sender and you haven't flushed it.

Comment: Length is correct, all the data has been put in the write(), BufferReader has been removed. I used flush after sending the file- it helped, reader no longer halts, 1176/1776 bytes are received.Still, the errors inside remain. The whole stream is moved a few bytes, and those beginning bytes are garbage. Is there something like "flush" but from input side? Force everything out of stream

Comment: Added full code to main body. Multithreading is still work in progress. Also, changed the save-to filename, to one that you get from the sender.

Comment: it was not me, nor do I know who it was (some random person, gave me plus and you a minus I think). I give you my plus, for while I did not solve the problem yet, it's true you are greatly helping me.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you. I didn't do it exactly the way you suggested, for editing the whole project to use that streams would kill me, but still :D Using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream was the key.

Comment: No it wasn't. *Not* using the `BufferedReader`,a HD using the code I posted *verbatim,* was the key. `DataInput/OutputStream` don't have magical properties.